# Tasks not shown in DAG when put in parallel pipeline

Tags: mysql, airflow, google-bigquery

I have four operation to extract MySQL's table into BigQuery using Airflow. I break my task into 2 steps, extract from MySQL to GCS then load GCS Json into BQ for each table (I have four table from MySQL, so it will be 8 tasks).

I have put my tasks like this:

```
[
task_extract_table_A>>task_load_table_A,
task_extract_table_B>>task_load_table_B,
task_extract_table_C>>task_load_table_C,
task_extract_table_D>>task_load_table_D
]
```

But, in my dashboard, only extraction and loading for table A,B and C are shown, not table D. Anyone know what's happen with this pipeline?

I use same DAG declaration for each tables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need square braces over it `[]`. Just use the following:

```py
task_extract_table_A>>task_load_table_A,
task_extract_table_B>>task_load_table_B,
task_extract_table_C>>task_load_table_C,
task_extract_table_D>>task_load_table_D
```